# Showing the joint density is Gaussian.

Tags: probability

Suppose we have the jointly varying random variables $(a,b) \in \mathbb{R}^2$ with $a \sim \mathcal{N}(0, \sigma^2)$ and the conditional density of $b|a \sim \mathcal{N}(a, \gamma^2)$. Show that the joint density of $(a,b)$ is Gaussian.

So we know that 
$$P(a,b) = P(a)P(b|a) \propto \exp\left[\dfrac{-a^2}{2\sigma^2} -\dfrac{(b-a)^2}{2\gamma^2}\right], \tag{a}$$
then I tried to show that I could write (a) as
$$\exp\left[\dfrac{-1}{2}(a-m_1,b-m_2)\Sigma^{-1}(a-m_1,b-m_2)^T\right]$$
where
$$\Sigma = \left[\begin{array}{c c}\sigma^2 & x \\ x & \gamma^2\end{array}\right]$$
and $x,m_1$ and $m_2$ are to be determined.

To find these values I just set
$$\dfrac{-1}{2}(a-m_1,b-m_2)\Sigma^{-1}(a-m_1,b-m_2)^T = \dfrac{-a^2}{2\sigma^2} -\dfrac{(b-a)^2}{2\gamma^2}$$
and tried to match coefficients based on powers of $a$ and $b$.

But after doing the calculations I cannot make all the powers of $a$ and $b$ disappear.

Comment: $b=a+N(0,\gamma^2)$ with two terms independent. Hence $(a,b)$ is jointly normal.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have the unconditional variance of b equal to its conditional variance, which can't be unless x=0. You can get the appropriate variance to put in $\Sigma_{22}$ (in terms of your "x") using the schur complement. Also you know $m_1=0$ and $m_2$ is determined by $x$. It could get messy so maybe reduce to the univariate case (cramer-wold), namely, for any scalars $u,v$, $ua+bv$ is normal. So $ua+vb$ given $a=a_0$ is distributed as $ua_0+v(b|a_0) \sim N((u+v)a_0,v^2\gamma^2)$. Then integrate against $a_0 \sim N(0,\sigma^2)$ to get another normal.